# How should I organize my go files to support cross platform builds and enforce consistency?

Tags: go, projects-and-solutions

I'm currently using a method where I have a "base" file that defines the types, interfaces and a basic API for the package. I then create an `_windows.go` and `_linux.go` file and add platform specific types that I can apply the interface to. The setup is basically like this: http://play.golang.org/p/2DJxTuSAIh.

1. Is this considered best practice?
2. Would this assist in a team setting where some developers are linux focused and some windows focused, i.e. if the interface changes both teams will be notified via build failure?

Comment: What do you mean by "precompile build directives"? (BTW, you can look at the `os`, `syscall`, and `net` packages if you want more confirmation on how to do handle multiple platforms)

Comment: *build constraints, I've updated the question

Comment: These *are* build constraints. They work exactly the same.

Comment: My understanding is that the build tool won't even read the file using the underscore method

Comment: In that sense, yes, the build tool will "read" the build constraint line then skip the file, but the outcome is the same.

Comment: @JimB Great suggestion on reading the source for those packages. Really sheds some light on organization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of interfaces is an orthogonal concept. Use an interface where an interface makes sense, but it's often simpler just provide an implementation by the same name in the proper GOOS and GOARCH files.

The method of using a common constructor name (from your example) is also used in places in the std lib, as is the method of assigning a global variable name to a function (which is similar in concept to the former method).

Because Go is statically typed, and you can't redeclare global identifiers, the build system will always catch problems; it's just a matter of testing for all applicable systems to ensure that no OS or ARCH has an out of date implementation.

Comment: Thanks. The interfaces were starting to make me ask "why don't I just have the same method in each of these files?" Just to make sure I've got it, in looking in the net library, there's this [_stub](https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/ipv4/icmp_stub.go) file. That's only there so that the implementation doesn't break when built on windows, but also because there is no _windows file, correct?

Comment: @scottm: yes, there's nothing special about _stub.go, it just has a `!linux` build constraint to provide an empty implementation for all other platforms.   If `sysICMPFilter` was added to a `_windows.go` file one day , they could add `!windows` in the stub file constraints to make the build work again.